# Razor: Table does not expand when a large screen is used

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am using  in my ASP .NET Razor Page and it scales very nicely when i decrease the width of my browser. However, when i increase the width of my browser, it does not increase anymore. I want it to increase in size as it has too much white space on the sides.

In the code below i tried style="width:100%" or even changing the margins but it doesn't scale due to large screens. I also tried using container-fluid class and it doesn't work. Need a solution.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Bob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bobby</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the display as table

```
display:table
```

If the table is inside any other tags like div, try setting it width to 100% as well and the display of div is block

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the table in a `container-flex`? (Bootstrap 4) If not the 100% table width is the same as the normal Bootstrap container width where the table is in.

```
<div class="container-flex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">

            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Bob</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Bobby</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```